# display: block для ссылки

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтоб у `a` был `display: block`, но при этом кнопка и дата не съезжали вниз.

```css
li {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #CECECE;
}

.date {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

li button {
  float: right;
  height: 30px;
  color: #3A3A3A;
  background-color: #FC5757;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  /*display: block;*/ /*вот что мне надо*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Что я делаю не так, как сделать ссылке `display:block`, но чтоб это не смещало кнопку и дату?

Comment: Возможно вам подойдет display: inline-block;?

Answer (score 1):

Поменять a и кнопку с датой местами.

```css
.c1, .date {
   float: right;
}

li {
   display: block;
   clear: both;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
   background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="c1"><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="c1"><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

или у a сделать float: left;

```css
a {
   float: left;
}    

.c1, .date {
   float: right;
}

li {
   display: block;
   clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button class="c1"><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button class="c1"><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: в результате я хочу получить: `a` - ссылка, которая занимает все пространство `li` до даты. Дата и кнопка находятся в `li` справа от `a`

Comment: @Nikita тогда смотрите пункты 2 и 4

Comment: Пробую, не получается. Если у `li` `display: block`, тогда пропадают номера `list-style-type`. А если у `a` `float: left`, тогда она не во всю ширину `li`.

Comment: @Nikita попробуйте у li сделать display: block; а дальше как я написал в ответе, я ответ обновил, с учётом вашего пояснения

Comment: @Nikita я ещё раз обновил ответ, в первом случае сделал раскладку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не совсем то, что я пытаюсь сделать. Мне надо, чтоб при клике в любую точку `li`, была ссылка `а`, для этого у `a` надо сделать `display: block`, когда я его делаю, то смещается кнопка и дата. В тех примерах, что вы прикрепили, во втором примере, если у `a` поставить `display: block`, то от не сработает. Так же, при `display: block` у `li` `list-style-type: decimal` не работает.

Comment: @Nikita я поправил, смотрите первый пример из моего ответа

Answer (score 0):

**list-style-type: decimal** - работает

```css
li {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  list-style-type: decimal; 
}
li>div {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #CECECE;
}

.date {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

li button {
  float: right;
  height: 30px;
  color: #3A3A3A;
  background-color: #FC5757;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

a {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </div></li>
    <li><div>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </div></li>
    <li><div>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </div></li>
    <li><div>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </div></li>
    <li><div>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </div></li>
    <li><div>
    <a href="#">Название</a>
    <button><span>X</span></button>
    <span class="date">13.04</span>
  </div></li>
</ul>
```